# how to configure opencv2.4.8 in python3.4.0

Tags: python, opencv

I have entered the folder `..\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86` and copied file `cv2.pyd` to the folder `..\python\Lib\site-packages`, but it does not work when I input `import cv2`.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup.html#py-table-of-content-setup

Comment: sorry, I can not open the url, can you show me the steps of how to configure it in detail?

Comment: Well the configuration is but lengthy so I have downloaded the webpages from the official website and uploaded here so that you can view them offline. Download the webpages from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/t65het4ersd0pv0/opencv.rar?dl=0

Comment: I still can not open the url, my email is ruan875417@qq.com, can you send it to my email? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after copying the file cv2.pyd, import cv2 via python command prompt first,

C:\User.......>python

->>>import cv2

if no error is displayed, that means opencv has been imported in python. Now, you can

->>>exit

and use "import cv2" in the code